# Twilio Messaging Webhook - Unsupported Media Type - Asp.net Core 3.1 API

Tags: asp.net-core, twilio, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an asp.net core (3.1) web api with an endpoint to accept the Twilio Messaging Webhook. When I run it locally from postman it works, when the webhook posts, I get an 415 "Unsupported Media Type"

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class TwillioController : TwilioController
{
    [HttpPost("ProcessIncomingMessage")]
    public TwiMLResult ProcessIncomingMessage(SmsRequest incomingMessage)
    {
      Console.WriteLine($"Recieved new SMS from {incomingMessage.From}");
      var messagingResponse = new MessagingResponse();
      messagingResponse.Message("The copy cat says: " +
                                incomingMessage.Body);

      return TwiML(messagingResponse);
    }
  }
```

It works when I have Content-Type:application/json in the header in postman.

I have also tried adding

```
[Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]
```

as well as

```
[Consumes("application/xml")]
```

and both still get the unsupported media type... can not figure out what Twilio is sending over or what I need to do to make it compatibly with their webhook.

Answer (score 9):

As the other answers mention, Twilio sends requests with a content type of `x-www-form-urlencoded`. Actions in controllers annotated with the `[ApiController]` attribute need to have a `[FromForm]` attribute on the parameter to work, like this:

```
[ApiController]
public class TwilioController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("")]
    public TwiMLResult Post([FromForm] SmsRequest request)
    {
        // do stuff with the SMS request
    }
}
```

While you can include a `[Consumes]` attribute, it isn't necessary.

Answer (score 2):

So I realized the ApiController was what was throwing it off. I removed all of the attributes and added the correct routes in startup and it works.

```
 public class SmsController : TwilioController
  {
    public TwiMLResult WebHook(SmsRequest incomingMessage)
    {
      var messagingResponse = new MessagingResponse();
      if (incomingMessage != null)
      {
        messagingResponse.Message($"The copy cat says: {incomingMessage.Body}");
      }
      else
      {
        messagingResponse.Message($"Recieved SMS but body was null");
      }


      return TwiML(messagingResponse);
    }
  }
```

Added an endpoint on startup

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
name: "sms",
pattern: "sms/{Action}",
defaults: new { Controller = "Sms"});
```

And the webhook URL is https://OURURL/sms/WebHook

Comment: The endpoint explicit route config is not needed, the usual `app.UseRouting();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapControllers());` work fine. Indeed, decorating the controller with `[ApiController]` causes this error.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the details of what Twilio is sending to your application, so `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is 100% correct.

[Webhooks FAQ](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/webhooks/webhooks-faq)

"For inbound text messages, Twilio will send an HTTP POST request to your server with a body that uses the application/x-www-form-urlencoded encoding. View the [list of parameters](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/twiml#twilios-request-to-your-application) sent in that request."

If it works when you set the `Content-Type:application/json` in the header in postman, then something is off since it should expect and consume `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: So when I add [Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")] to the call, the consumes attribute docs say it looks for the parameter "Content-Type" which Twilio is not sending in its headers. So even when I set it to expect it, I get the error because the API can not determine the media type. I tried adding an attribute to add the header... no luck.

Comment: This is what I see in the Twilio Webhook when sending an SMS, `Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8`